# Realm.io database diagram

Tags: android, database, realm

Is there a way to generate database diagram for [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#getting-started)? I'm using it in my Android project.

Comment: Requests for off site resources are off topic. Please describe the problem *and what has been attempted to solve it*

Comment: Well there's the Realm-Browser which runs on MAC

Comment: As far as I can see, the Realm Broser doesn't have a diagram functionality.